# Array differential compare multple array list

Tags: php, arrays

How to compare 3 or more array list in array differential? I use this code but its seems only 2 array is comparing. Did I do something wrong?

```
$purchaseorderinventory=mysqli_query($link,"select * from purchaseorder where ITEM_CODE_MX='".$value."' and SHIP_TO_MX='".$display_branchcode."' and STATUS_PO_MX='RECEIVED'");
    while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($purchaseorderinventory))
                                    {
                                  $imeipo[]=$row3["IMEI_MX"];


            }
                        $implodepo = implode(",",$imeipo);
                        $explodepo = explode(',', $implodepo);

    $beginventory=mysqli_query($link,"select * from inventory where ITEM_CODE_MX='".$value."' and BRANCH_CODE_MX='".$display_branchcode."'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($beginventory))
                                    {

                                    $cid=$row["ID_INVENTORY"];
                                     $itemcode=$row["ITEM_CODE_MX"];
                                     $itemquantity=$row["ITEM_QUANTITY_MX"];
                                     $imei=$row["IMEI_MX"];
                                     $site=$row["SITE_CODE_MX"];
                                    $begexplode = explode(',', $imei);


                                    }
    $transfer=mysqli_query($link,"select * from transferinventory where ITEM_CODE_MX='".$value."' and SITE_FROM_MX='".$display_branchcode."'");
    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($transfer))
                                    {


         $imeitransfer[]=$row2["IMEI_MX"];


                        }

                        $implodeimeitransfer = implode(",",$imeitransfer);
                        $transferexplode = explode(',', $implodeimeitransfer);
                        //diffrence
        $inventorydiff = array_diff($transferexplode,$explodepo,$begexplode);

                        $finalimplode = implode(",",$inventorydiff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare and check if the size of returned array is zero. If zero, that means all the 3 are equal.

```
if(empty(array_diff($array1, $array2, $array2))){
 echo "All three are equal";
}
else
  echo "they are not not equal";
```

Comment: they are not equal sir